# Invoke a static method on a Java class stored in a var

Tags: java, reflection, clojure

I'm processing a stream of events, encoded as Google Protobuffers, stored as bytes. The trick with Protobuffers is that you must know the class of a thing before you attempt to load that thing. Another trick is that the event I'm loading is nested.

So. I have the `ByteArray` of the innermost event. Fortunately, there's a field in the next-to-innermost event which specifies the type of the innermost event, so I can figure out what class should load it.

Good news: the parse function has the same name (`parseFrom`) on every candidate class.
Bad news: the function I need to call is static, and dispatches on both arity and type.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
(ns do-the-thing
  (import com.thing.place Type$Subtype Type$SecondSubType)

(def decl-obj-map
  {:type-subtype Type$SubType
   :type-second-subtype Type$Second$SubType})

(defn call-fn
  [class n-args method]
  (let [o (gensym)
        args (repeatedly n-args gensym)
        assure-symbol (fn [thing] (if (symbol? thing) thing (symbol thing)))
        method (assure-symbol method)]
    (eval
     `(fn [~o ~@args]
        (. ~(with-meta o {:tag class})
           (~method ~@args))))))

(def event-type (.getSubtypeField event-obj)
(def parse-func (call-fn (event-type decl-obj-map) 0 "parseFrom")

(parse-func (.getByteArrayFromInnerObj inner-obj))
```

So. This doesn't work at all. Instead of `call-fn`, I've also tried [this method](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.reflect/call-method) from `clojure.contrib`. It throws the ever-inscruitable `IllegalArgumentException array element type mismatch  java.lang.reflect.Array.set (Array.java:-2)` error.

Anyone?

Comment: Gastove, I it would help if you could write a simplified illustration of the problem.  I have to work pretty hard to figure out what part of the code above illustrates the points in the text description.  (Also, there are no comments flagging what's relevant.)  Anyone trying to help has to work through most of the code bit by bit from scratch to figure it out.  Others may find it easier to follow than I do, but with a different presentation, you could tap a broader range of people to help provide answers.

Comment: @Mars apologies -- this is already a simplification of my code; guess I didn't go far enough. I'll edit the question soon as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with that code as applied to static methods of a class, the most important being that the class has to be known at compile time for the dot special form and friends [Note: `(Class/method ...)` expands to `(. Class method ...)`]. Therefore, you would have to `eval` on each invocation with this strategy -- the `eval` would have to be moved inside the returned function (after patching it up a bit). That is undesirable.

You could solve this with reflection, for example

```
(defn call-fn [^Class class method] 
  (fn [& args] 
    (clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeStaticMethod 
      (.getName class) 
      (str method) 
      (to-array args))))


(def my-abs (call-fn Math "abs"))
(my-abs -1) ;=> 1
```

But I think you've over-engineered your problem. Instead of a map from type keywords to classes, consider a map from specs directly to functions, for example

```
(def spec->parser
  {:type-subtype {1 #(Type$Subtype/parseFrom %) 2 #(Type$Subtype/parseFrom % %2)} 
   :type-second-subtype {1 #(Type$SecondSubtype/parseFrom %) ...}})
```

Then your `call-fn` is just

```
(defn get-parser [type-kw nargs] (get-in spec->parser [type-kw nargs]))
```

or simply `#(get-in spec->parser &%)`

Comment: Oh, interesting. Okay, I understand the problem with my old approach -- let me give this a try, see if it works!

Comment: ...and yes, I know my approach appears over-engineered. The problem is, I'm ingesting a very flexible data model that gets updated frequently with new subclasses. I would prefer to not have to update my parser every time somebody adds a new class to the model, if possible -- but it does complicate things.